# project stopped unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to write code for getting my cords on the mobile.

I tried to debug the code and i guess error is in 
    LocationListener ll=new myLocationListener();

### trackmobileclass

```
package prakash.work.trackmobile;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class getCords extends Activity {

TextView longi;
TextView lat;
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_cords);

    longi=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);
    lat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);

    LocationManager lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll=new myLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);


}
class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        if(arg0 != null)
        {
            tv.setText("Working");
            double plongi=arg0.getLongitude();
            double plat=arg0.getLatitude();

            longi.setText(Double.toString(plongi));
            lat.setText(Double.toString(plat));
        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
}
```

### ##XML layout file##

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Latitude"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Longitude"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longi"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### ##Manifest##

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="prakash.work.trackmobile"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".getCords"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_get_cords" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Or is there anything else i need to look into 
How to work with listeners

Comment: u are getting this Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException...check some where you are getting null value

Comment: try putting this line TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); in onCreate() method....

Comment: thanks dude this is working fine now but i am not able to retreive the cords

Comment: @nagprakash you should mention here how you got the solution so that others can also find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

You need to put this in your `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` method after `setContentView(R.layout.get_cords);`

```
TextView longi;
TextView lat;
TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_cords);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    longi=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);
    lat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
```

Comment: If I solved your problem first, please give me the credit.  The other person simply reworded my answer.

Comment: Plus his answer does not take the `setContentView` into consideration

Comment: jack can you help me on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257344/unable-to-get-my-location-coordinates)

Answer (score -1):

You would normally look in the first couple of lines of the log cat (this one is the 5th line)
the error is unable to instiate the getcords. Try Rebooting emulator as this is also a known bug, if error recurs add the package in front of the .getCords
in the android manifest. (prakash.work.trackwork

Comment: i got my solution here i need to place TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); in text view .... after doing that i am not getting the expected results.....